# Case statement - not a group by expression error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query:

```
SELECT EMP_CD,
 EMP_NUM,
 to_char(PAY_DT,'yyyymm') as PAY_month,
 MAX(BILL_FREQ) as BILLING_FREQUENCY,
 MAX(FXD_CHRG) as FIXED_CHARGE, 
 SUM(Pay_1)/SUM(Pay_2) AS DEPT_CHARGE, 
 SUM(Pay_1)/SUM(Pay_2) AS SUB_CHARGE, 
WHERE EMP_CD in ('HP','2000') 
AND CODE in ('X','Y','Z') 
GROUP BY EMP_CD, EMP_NUM, TO_CHAR(PAY_DT,'yyyymm');
```

Now, I want to find the dept_charge for CODE in ('X','Y') and SUB_CHARGE in ('Z')
For that I have tried the below method:

```
SELECT EMP_CD,
 EMP_NUM,
 to_char(PAY_DT,'yyyymm') as PAY_month,
 MAX(BILL_FREQ) as BILLING_FREQUENCY,
 MAX(FXD_CHRG) as FIXED_CHARGE, 
 CASE WHEN CODE in ('X','Y') then SUM(Pay_1)/SUM(Pay_2) ELSE 0 END AS DEPT_CHARGE, 
 CASE WHEN CODE in ('Z') then SUM(Pay_1)/SUM(Pay_2) ELSE 0 END AS SUB_CHARGE, 
WHERE EMP_CD in ('HP','2000') 
AND CODE in ('X','Y','Z') 
GROUP BY EMP_CD, EMP_NUM, TO_CHAR(PAY_DT,'yyyymm');
```

I'm getting an error saying 'not a group by expression. Can anyone please tell me where am I doing wrong. Also, please suggest me, if there is another better approach to do it.

As an example..

```
EMP_NUM CODE    PAY_MONTH   PAY_1   PAY_2
552343  X         201006    32.82   547
552343  X         201006    36.12   602
552343  X         201006    33.12   552
552343  X         201006    33      550
552343  X         201006    32.82   547
```

for this dataset, I have to get 0.06 as dept_charge and 0 as sub_charge

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach is to have the aggregate function first.  I use subquery factoring (with clause) to aggregate at the  emp_cd, emp_num, pay_month, billing_frequency and fixed_charge level as an intermediate step:

```
       WITH ep AS
  (SELECT emp_cd,
    emp_num,
    TO_CHAR(pay_dt,'yyyymm') AS pay_month,
    code,
    MAX(bill_freq) AS billing_frequency,
    MAX(fxd_chrg)  AS fixed_charge,
    SUM( NVL(pay_1,0)) sum_pay1,
    SUM(NVL(pay_2, 0)) sum_pay2
  FROM emp_payments
  WHERE emp_cd IN ('HP','2000')
  AND code     IN ('X','Y','Z')
  GROUP BY emp_cd,
    emp_num,
    TO_CHAR(pay_dt,'yyyymm'),
    code
  )
SELECT emp_cd,
  emp_num,
  pay_month,
  billing_frequency,
  fixed_charge,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN code IN ('X','Y')
    THEN sum_pay1
    ELSE 0
  END ) / SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN code IN ('X','Y')
    THEN sum_pay2
    ELSE 0
  END ) AS dept_charge,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN code IN ('Z')
    THEN sum_pay1
    ELSE 0
  END ) / SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN code IN ('Z')
    THEN sum_pay2
    ELSE 0
  END ) AS sub_charge
FROM ep
GROUP BY emp_cd,
  emp_num,
  pay_month,
  billing_frequency,
  fixed_charge
```

Comment: It's not working patrick.. actually I need to divide the cumulative sum of Pay_1 for emp_num and to_char(PAY_DT,'yyyymm') group
by
cumulative sum of Pay_2 for the same group

Comment: As an example..
EMP_NUM CODE PAY_MONTH PAY_1 PAY_2
552343 X 201006 32.82 547
552343 X 201006 36.12 602
552343 X 201006 33.12 552
552343 X 201006 33 550
552343 X 201006 32.82 547

for this I have to get 0.06 as dept_charge and 0 as sub_charge

Comment: Thanks....so you need cumulative sums for both.  By the way, for the sake of posterity, can you place this additional info in the question above.

Comment: @user2942261 No problem.  I enjoy these types of problems.

Comment: Hey patrick, I have another question..if you have some time,could you please take a look at it.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063007/how-to-merge-my-queries-to-a-single-query-or-may-be-a-stored-proc

Comment: @user2942261 Looks like bacon bits provided a reasonable solution.