# How to merge my queries to a single query (or may be a stored proc..)

Tags: sql, oracle

Below are the queries in which I am calculating values for four attributes..

```
1.
Here I am calculating the values for chrg_orig


    with ep as
      (select emp_cd,
        emp_num,
        to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as pay_month,
        max(code),
        max(bill) as bill,
        max(chrg)  as charge,
        sum( nvl(pay_1,0)) sum_pay1,
        sum(nvl(pay_2, 0)) sum_pay2,
        (chrg_mon*22)+ (chrg_week*5)+ chrg_day as days,
      from emp_payments
      where emp_cd in ('HP','2000')
      and code     in ('X','Y','Z')
      group by emp_cd,
        emp_num,
        to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm'),
        code
      )
    select emp_cd,
      emp_num,
      pay_month,
      max(code),
      sum(bill)
      case when sum(days)=22 then sum(chrg) else  round((round(sum(chrg)/sum(days),4)*22),2) end as chrg_orig
    from ep
    where chrg <>0
    group by 
    emp_cd,
    emp_num,
    paymonth

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2.
Here I am calculating the values for rate_chrg

     with ep as
      (select emp_cd,
        emp_num,
        to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as pay_month,
        code,
        max(bill) as bill,
        max(chrg)  as charge,
        sum( nvl(pay_1,0)) sum_pay1,
        sum(nvl(pay_2, 0)) sum_pay2,
        (chrg_mon*22)+ (chrg_week*5)+ chrg_day as days,
      from emp_payments
      where emp_cd in ('HP','2000')
      and code     in ('X','Y','Z')
      group by emp_cd,
        emp_num,
        to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm'),
        code
      )
    (
    select a.emp_cd,a.emp_num,a.key,b.rate as rate_chrg from 
        (select emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as key,max(invc_dt) as invc_dt from ep
            where code in ('X','Y') and rate <> 0
            group by emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(invc_dt,'yyyymm')) a,

        (select emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as key,invc_dt,rate from ep
            where code in ('X','Y') and rate <> 0) b
    where a.emp_cd = b.emp_cd
    and a.emp_num = b.emp_num
    and a.key = b.key
    and a.invc_dt = b.invc_dt
    )



-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3.
Here I am calculating the values for bonus_chrg




    with ep as
      (select emp_cd,
        emp_num,
        to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as pay_month,
        code,
        max(bill) as bill,
        max(chrg)  as charge,
        sum( nvl(pay_1,0)) sum_pay1,
        sum(nvl(pay_2, 0)) sum_pay2,
        (chrg_mon*22)+ (chrg_week*5)+ chrg_day as days,
      from emp_payments
      where emp_cd in ('HP','2000')
      and code     in ('X','Y','Z')
      group by emp_cd,
        emp_num,
        to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm'),
        code
      )
    (
    select a.emp_cd,a.emp_num,a.key,b.rate as bonus_chrg from 
        (select emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as key,max(invc_dt) as invc_dt from ep
            where code in ('Z') and rate <> 0
            group by emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(invc_dt,'yyyymm')) a,

        (select emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as key,invc_dt,rate from ep
            where code in ('Z') and rate <> 0) b
    where a.emp_cd = b.emp_cd
    and a.emp_num = b.emp_num
    and a.key = b.key
    and a.invc_dt = b.invc_dt
    )

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4.
Here I am calculating the values for comp_days



    with ep as
      (select emp_cd,
        emp_num,
        to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as pay_month,
        code,
        max(bill) as bill,
        max(chrg)  as charge,
        sum( nvl(pay_1,0)) sum_pay1,
        sum(nvl(pay_2, 0)) sum_pay2,
        (chrg_mon*22)+ (chrg_week*5)+ chrg_day as days,
      from emp_payments
      where emp_cd in ('HP','2000')
      and code     in ('X','Y','Z')
      group by emp_cd,
        emp_num,
        to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm'),
        code
      )
    (
    select emp_cd,emp_num,paymonth as key,sum(days) as comp_days from ep
    where code in ('X','Y')
    group by emp_cd,emp_num,key
    )

--------------------------------------------------
```

What I have done so far is, I have taken all these separate queries into ETL tool and did a left outer join with chrg_orig as the driving table and assigned zeros for non-matching columns.
But I think I need to have a full outer join(which I was not able to implement it in the tool) and assign zeros for all non matching values.

I want to club these queries into a single query..what is the best approach to solve it?
All inputs and suggestions are valuable.Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [more than one virtual table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6507/multiple-operations-using-with) with a CTE by separating the CTE definitions with commas.  Futhermore, CTEs can refer to other CTEs.

Assuming `ep` is the same across all these queries, you can do something like this:

```
 with ep as
    (select emp_cd,
      emp_num,
      to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as pay_month,
      max(code),
      max(bill) as bill,
      max(chrg)  as charge,
      sum( nvl(pay_1,0)) sum_pay1,
      sum(nvl(pay_2, 0)) sum_pay2,
      (chrg_mon*22)+ (chrg_week*5)+ chrg_day as days,
    from emp_payments
    where emp_cd in ('HP','2000')
    and code     in ('X','Y','Z')
    group by emp_cd,
      emp_num,
      to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm'),
      code
    ),
 chrg_orig (<field names here>) as (
  select emp_cd,
    emp_num,
    pay_month,
    max(code),
    sum(bill)
    case when sum(days)=22 then sum(chrg) else  round((round(sum(chrg)/sum(days),4)*22),2) end as chrg_orig
  from ep
  where chrg <>0
  group by 
  emp_cd,
  emp_num,
  paymonth
),
rate_chrg (<field names here>) as (
  select a.emp_cd,a.emp_num,a.key,b.rate as rate_chrg from 
      (select emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as key,max(invc_dt) as invc_dt from ep
          where code in ('X','Y') and rate <> 0
          group by emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(invc_dt,'yyyymm')) a,

      (select emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as key,invc_dt,rate from ep
          where code in ('X','Y') and rate <> 0) b
  where a.emp_cd = b.emp_cd
  and a.emp_num = b.emp_num
  and a.key = b.key
  and a.invc_dt = b.invc_dt
  ),
bonus_chrg (<field names here>) as (
  select a.emp_cd,a.emp_num,a.key,b.rate as bonus_chrg from 
      (select emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as key,max(invc_dt) as invc_dt from ep
          where code in ('Z') and rate <> 0
          group by emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(invc_dt,'yyyymm')) a,

      (select emp_cd,emp_num,to_char(pay_dt,'yyyymm') as key,invc_dt,rate from ep
          where code in ('Z') and rate <> 0) b
  where a.emp_cd = b.emp_cd
  and a.emp_num = b.emp_num
  and a.key = b.key
  and a.invc_dt = b.invc_dt
  ),
comp_days (<field names here>) as (
  select emp_cd,emp_num,paymonth as key,sum(days) as comp_days from ep
  where code in ('X','Y')
  group by emp_cd,emp_num,key
  )
SELECT *
FROM ep
LEFT OUTER JOIN chrg_orig
  ON <JOIN CONDITION>
LEFT OUTER JOIN rate_chrg
  ON <JOIN CONDITION>
LEFT OUTER JOIN bonus_chrg
  ON <JOIN CONDITION>
LEFT OUTER JOIN comp_days
  ON <JOIN CONDITION>
```

Comment: @user2942261 That's hard to answer because performance is going to vary a lot depending on the queries, your data, and so on.  There might be a better way to pull the data period, like aggregating your data with the `OVER()` clause, which could allow multiple aggregate functions in the same statement with fewer CTEs or subqueries.  It depends on your situation.